# How do I use TextWriter.Synchronized in netcoreapp1.1

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to use [TextWriter.Synchronized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized(v=vs.110).aspx) method in my app. My target framework is: `netcoreapp1.1`.

This is the program I am trying to compile:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var log = File.CreateText("out.log"))
            {
                var syncedLog = TextWriter.Synchronized(log);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

This is my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Unfortunatelly, this does not work:

```
> dotnet run
  Program.cs(12,47): error CS0117: 'TextWriter' does not contain a definition for 'Synchronized'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `TextWriter.Synchronized` does not exist on .Net Core 1.1, you will have to implement it yourself. As a start, you can use [the .Net Core 2.0 implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a8f20ac/src/System.Runtime.Extensions/src/System/IO/TextWriter.cs#L613-L813). You won't be able to use that code directly, because it extensively uses `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`, which is also not supported on .Net Core 1.1. But you can replace that with `lock (this)` in each such method.